# How to keep jenkins agent online after I restart my remote desktop

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, agent

I am new to Jenkins and currently I have to test machine Test1 and Test2 on the test machines , I run ranorex automation tests , every thing works fine until i start getting the issue and that is when I restart my remote desktop(Test1 machine) and remote desktop(Test2 machine) both machine does not comes online on jenkins dashboard and appears as offline , then when I manually start both machine then on dashboard they both came online and my test execution works , previously i tried to use jenkins as service which some how block my automation test execution and error comes "The system needs to be interactive" , so I disabled jenkins service for Windows Service which solves my "The system needs to be interactive" error but I landed with this issue , whenever I perform restart my both test machines went offline

Any help in this regards

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a schedule task with the 'On Startup' trigger, this is how I'm doing it and it works well.

Comment: Thanks for reply , can you give more details how are you doing ?

Comment: When you go to the agent page on jenkins web interface, it shows you how to run the agent from command-line (using java)
So, on the agent itself, create a scheduled task, with the 'Action' being that command line , and 'Trigger' being 'On Startup'